# How to load an image from a website into a UIPageControl?

Tags: uiwebview, uipagecontrol

I really like to know how to load a specific image from a website into a UIPageController.
It's a little bit confusing for me, maybe because I'm a beginner, I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do multiple things at once

- Load the image data with e.g. `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theImageURL]`, or better, do it asynchronously via `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`.
- Create an image from the data: `[UIImage imageWithData:theData]`
- Initialize an `UIImageView` with that image
- Add it to the page control

If you don't know the image URL, you'll have to parse the HTML and extract it with something like `NSXMLParser`

Comment: I'm going to try what you wrote yesterday... Before I try this, can you tell me if the picture I want to have in my PageController will change when the picture in the website changes? So that my PageController is always "actual"?

Comment: Programming is not some kind of magic, you actually have to write that stuff yourself. No, it will not update automatically. If the website just consists of the ONE image, you could add the `UIWebView` directly to the `UIPageController`, and reload it when the view controller get's pushed, or the App gets active again.